# PyCharm: Jupyter server stopped

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I have installed `PyCharm Professional` and I want to run `Jupyter notebook` in it, but whenever I try to run a cell, a message appears saying `Jupyter server stopped` with this message error:

```
Jupyter server process finishedTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\untitled\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\untitled\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 49, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\untitled\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\untitled\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\untitled\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\untitled\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\untitled\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 35, in select_backend
    reraise(ImportError, ImportError("Importing %s failed with %s" % (name, e)), exc_info[2])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\untitled\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\untitled\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
ImportError: Importing zmq.backend.cython failed with invalid syntax (__init__.py, line 5)
```

I have already installed the Jupyter package and I can run Jupyter outside PyCharm, has someone faced this problem?
if so, can you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Check if you are calling the same jupyter executable. e.g. `which jupyter` from the OS terminal and `which jupyter` from pycharm's terminal. I guess in windows there's `where` command instead of `which`. e.g. `where jupyter` 
https://superuser.com/questions/207707/what-is-windows-equivalent-of-the-which-command-in-unix-is-there-an-equivale

Comment: yes, they both return the same result C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Scripts\jupyter.exe